# How would I resolve dns with Rancher container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, dns, rancher

We have few rancher hosts in few different datacenters. The Issue I am trying solve is:

Get DC Rancher app to resolve or connect to AWS rancher container and we have VPN between so the network is pretty much wide open. I could potentially do everything through public interfaces however am more interested to isolate it to private network between DC and AWS.

Comment: Is your on premise network linked or integrated with your  AWS Vpc?

Comment: Yes, its direct connect - wide open between all networks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Working with Private Hosted Zones:

"If you have integrated your on-premises network with one or more Amazon VPC virtual networks and you want your on-premises network to resolve domain names in private hosted zones, you can create a Simple AD directory. Simple AD provides IP addresses that you can use to submit DNS queries from your on-premises network to your private hosted zone. For more information, see Getting Started with Simple AD in the AWS Directory Service Administration Guide."

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html

See the Custom DNS Servers section and how to use Simple AD to resolve DNS for your use case.

Comment: Not sure how AD comes into play with my issues. Assuming that AD was just an example.

Comment: Simple AD provides IP addresses that you can use to submit DNS queries from your on-premises network to your private hosted zone. For more information, see Getting Started with Simple AD in the AWS Directory Service Administration Guide.

Comment: I can just use bind or unbound for that purpose, it is what actually I have issues with.